# get and save youtube thumbnail to web server

Tags: php, youtube, download, thumbnails, save

So I know that I can retrieve the youtube thumbnail by going here:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/BoVBdxftEF8/0.jpg

obviously the ID changes based on the video. I want to write a script that I can get save the photo from that URL to a folder say called 'video_thumbnails'. Is there a somewhat simple way of doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
file_put_contents ("video_thumbnails/thumb.jpg",file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/BoVBdxftEF8/0.jpg"));
```

Comment: How can i make it so the folder is only writeable by a person who's logged in? I don't want the permissions to be 777 obviously but that's the only way the file writing works. Any ideas?